# How to find the points of intersection of a line and multiple curves in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, equation

I have data represented in the figure.

[image]

The curves were extrapolated and I have a line whose equation is known. The equation of curves are unknown. Now, how do I find the points of intersection of this line with each of the curves?

The reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate


x = np.array([[0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08],
              [0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09],
              [0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1],
              [0.17, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11],
              [0.19, 0.17, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12],
              [0.22, 0.19, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13],
              [0.24, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16, 0.14],
              [0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.18, 0.15],
              [0.29, 0.26, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16]])

y = np.array([[71.64, 78.52, 84.91, 89.35, 97.58],
              [66.28, 73.67, 79.87, 85.36, 93.24],
              [61.48, 69.31, 75.36, 81.87, 89.35],
              [57.61, 65.75, 71.7, 79.1, 86.13],
              [55.12, 63.34, 69.32, 77.29, 83.88],
              [54.58, 62.54, 68.7, 76.72, 82.92],
              [56.58, 63.87, 70.3, 77.69, 83.53],
              [61.67, 67.79, 74.41, 80.43, 85.86],
              [70.08, 74.62, 80.93, 85.06, 89.84]])


x1 = np.linspace(0, 0.4, 100)
y1 = -100 * x1 + 100
plt.figure(figsize = (5.15,5.15))
plt.subplot(111)
for i in range(5):
    x_val = np.linspace(x[0, i] - 0.05, x[-1, i] + 0.05, 100)
    x_int = np.interp(x_val, x[:, i], y[:, i])
    poly = np.polyfit(x[:, i], y[:, i], deg=2)
    y_int  = np.polyval(poly, x_val)
    plt.plot(x[:, i], y[:, i], linestyle = '', marker = 'o')
    plt.plot(x_val, y_int, linestyle = ':', linewidth = 0.25, color =  'black')
plt.plot(x1, y1, linestyle = '-.', linewidth = 0.5, color =  'black')


plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We *do* know the equations of the curves. They are of the form `a*x**2 + b*x + c`, where `a`,`b`, and `c` are the elements of the vector returned by `np.polyfit`. Then we just need to find the roots of a quadratic equation in order to find the intersections:

```
def quadratic_intersections(p, q):
    """Given two quadratics p and q, determines the points of intersection"""
    x = np.roots(np.asarray(p) - np.asarray(q))
    y = np.polyval(p, x)
    return x, y
```

The above function isn't super robust: there doesn't *need* to be a real root, and it doesn't really check for that. You're free to make it better.

Anyways, we give `quadratic_intersections` two quadratics, and it returns the two points of intersection. Putting it into your code, we have:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 0.4, 100)
y1 = -100 * x1 + 100
plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
plt.subplot(111)

plt.plot(x1, y1, linestyle = '-.', linewidth = 0.5, color =  'black')
for i in range(5):
    x_val = np.linspace(x[0, i] - 0.05, x[-1, i] + 0.05, 100)
    poly = np.polyfit(x[:, i], y[:, i], deg=2)
    y_int  = np.polyval(poly, x_val)
    plt.plot(x[:, i], y[:, i], linestyle = '', marker = 'o')
    plt.plot(x_val, y_int, linestyle = ':', linewidth = 0.25, color =  'black')
    ix = quadratic_intersections(poly, [0, -100, 100])
    plt.scatter(*ix, marker='x', color='black', s=40, linewidth=2)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlim([0,.35])
plt.ylim([40,110])
plt.show()
```

This makes the following figure:

[image]

Now, if you don't know that the functions you are dealing with are polynomials, you can use the optimization tools in [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) to find the root. For example:

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style

matplotlib.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
%matplotlib inline

f = lambda x: np.cos(x) - x
g = np.sin

h = lambda x: f(x) - g(x)

x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
plt.plot(x, f(x), zorder=1)
plt.plot(x, g(x), zorder=1)

x_int = scipy.optimize.fsolve(h, 1.0)
y_int = f(x_int)

plt.scatter(x_int, y_int, marker='x', s=150, zorder=2, 
            linewidth=2, color='black')

plt.xlim([0,3])
plt.ylim([-4,2])
```

Which plots:

[image]

Comment: This is great, but in case I have an unknown function, what can be done?

Comment: can you share your mpl config file? I find this plot very beautiful ^^

Comment: Might be better to return separate coordinate arrays from `quadratic_intersections`, for example `x = np.roots(np.asarray(p) - q); y = np.polyval(p, x); return x, y`.

Comment: @Juanlu001 I'm just using the `fivethirtyeight` style file that comes with recent versions of matplotlib. That is, `import matplotlib.style; matplot.style.use('fivethirtyeight')`.

Comment: @nxkryptor What do you mean by "unknown function"? Which function is unknown? What *is* known about it?

Comment: @GarethRees Thanks, that *is* much cleaner! I've updated my answer.

Comment: @jme, I meant for this case, the functions are known, what if they were arbitrary curves?

Comment: @nxkryptor I think I see what you're saying... in this case the functions are quadratic polynomials, so we can find the intersection by finding the root of another quadratic polynomial. But what if we have a function `f` that isn't a polynomial? You could do two things: 1) approximate it with a polynomial and do the above, or 2) find the intersection using the tools in `scipy.optimize`. I've added a description of the latter to my answer.