# Draw a vertical line on PCA chart where Y-axis is 0.9

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pca

I am trying to draw a straight line in the PCA plot (Plot image attached) at the point where the curve meets 0.9 in Y -axis and the vertical line should meet the x axis at a number say (6 in this case). I have attached the image and the code.

In simple words, I would like to have a vertical line drawn to meet the x-axis where the red and black lines meet

Could someone please help me?

```
pca = decomposition.PCA().fit(df_scaled)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_), color='k', lw=2)
plt.xlabel('Number of components')
plt.ylabel('Total explained variance')
plt.xlim(0, 63)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.axvline(0.9, c='b')
plt.axhline(0.9, c='r')

plt.savefig('PCA.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you've got a point in `np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)` that is exactly 0.9 (which is unlikely), you'll have to interpolate between the two adjacent points to find where along the x axis you want to draw your `axvline`

Comment: But if you just want the vertical line at 6, as you mention in your question, just use `plt.axvline(6, c='b')`

Comment: Does [How to find the points of intersection of a line and multiple curves in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904423/how-to-find-the-points-of-intersection-of-a-line-and-multiple-curves-in-python) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Find x value when y is 0.9 on a curve.

- Use one of the various curve fitting methods from (numpy, scipy, other, write your own) to get a function/callable that will return a y value for a given x value - call it **f**
- Write a function, **g**, that that takes an x argument and returns the difference between `f(x)` and 0.9

  - ```
    def g(x): return f(x) - 0.9
    ```
- Use one of the various  optimization methods from a (numpy, scipy, other, write your own) to minimize the error returned by `g`
- Plot a line at that x value